# NSTimer in Cocos2d Application

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d documents it is written that it is not a good idea to use NSTimer. Why is it not recommended to use NSTimer. I know there is a schedule method of Cocos2d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try NOT to use Cocoa’s NSTimer. Instead use cocos2d’s own scheduler.
If you use cocos2d scheduler, you will have:

- automatic pause/resume.
- when the
  CCLayer (CCScene, CCSprite, CCNode)
  enters the stage the timer will be

  - automatically activated, and when it
    leaves the stage it will be
  - automatically deactivated. Your
    target/selector will be called with a
    delta time

from here (old broken link)
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices

updated link
http://ec2-50-16-191-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices

I would add you are adding some unwanted overhead too. If you have a lot of timers that could be a good bit of overhead.

Comment: @madmik2 Thanks! I just replaced one of my timers with schedule method. Now, I have only one NSTimer in my application. Thanks for your input!