# How to call a method once per second in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

My program has a loop that does calculation and drawing like 60 times a second. I want my movement action be executed only once a second, how do I do that with objective-c methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Cocos2D for iphone you MUST NOT use the NSTimer.

Following the [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3abest_practices#timers), you should use the `schedule:interval:` method like that:

```
[self schedule: @selector(tick:) interval:1.0f];

- (void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Well, you __can__ use NSTimer, although it is highly discouraged :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

For one second:

```
NSTimer *yourTastTimer = scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:yourTarget selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES;
```

You can check the documentation for [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for details.

**Edit**

You may also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449104/1477887).

Answer (score 0):

If your using a CCSprite ,they have a schedule method which might do the trick.
Basically do what for the main loop. 
You could also keep a ticker in your main loop and check that this is the ticker%60==0.
Then call your movement action.

I read NSTimer is discouraged with cocos2d [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225227/nstimer-in-cocos2d-application).